# Mapping java.util.Date to xs:date instead of xs:dateTime in JAX-WS

Tags: java, datetime, date, jax-ws

We hav an EJB,  jws-anotated as a web service. It has a pretty complex pojo-model that generates an equally complex xsd. The pojos contain numerous java.util.Date. These all map to xs:dateTime.

This service is used as "business service" in Oracle(BEA) OSB(AquaLogic). We also have a "proxy service" which we map to the BS with XQuery (the OSB/AquaLogic way). The proxy service's xsd has xs:date for the corresponding fields.
For some reason, Oracle's implementation of XQuery does not support casting from xs:date to xs:dateTime(!).

I could solve this by casting to xs:string and concat:ing with "T00:00:00", however, i would rather try to get JAX-WS to generate an xsd with xs:date instead. Only, I can't find any info on how to do this (anotations?).

Can anyone give me a hint?

Kind regards,
Lars

Answer (score 3):

I don't know specifically about Oracle, but for CXF there are utilities to do this mapping.  You might be able to find a similar adapter for your config.  Have a look at the following page.  http://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html.

There are two options depending on whether you have your schema inside the WSDL or in a separate URL (I understand that your are in a Java first config, but that you are trying to do the conversion on the Proxy side).

```
<jaxws:bindings wsdlLocation="YOUR_WSDL_LOCATION"
          xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws"
          xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
          xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
          xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
  <jaxws:bindings  node="wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/xs:schema[@targetNamespace='THE_NAMESPACE_OF_YOUR_SCHEMA']">
      <jxb:globalBindings xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <jxb:javaType name="java.util.Date" xmlType="xs:dateTime"
                      parseMethod="org.apache.cxf.tools.common.DataTypeAdapter.parseDateTime"
                      printMethod="org.apache.cxf.tools.common.DataTypeAdapter.printDateTime"/>
      </jxb:globalBindings>
  </jaxws:bindings>
</jaxws:bindings>
```

XSD : outside, JAXB syntax

```
<jxb:bindings version="2.0"
              xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
              xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="file:<path><name>.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
    <jxb:globalBindings xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <jxb:javaType name="java.util.Date" xmlType="xs:dateTime" 
                    parseMethod="org.apache.cxf.tools.common.DataTypeAdapter.parseDateTime" 
                    printMethod="org.apache.cxf.tools.common.DataTypeAdapter.printDateTime"/>
    </jxb:globalBindings>
  </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

In our CXF, we use the mapping to avoid using Gregorian Calendar but you can probably use it to do the casting.